# Can I access SMS sounds on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, uilocalnotification, system-sounds

I was wondering if I can let the user choose an SMS sound, from the system sounds, for the Local notification of my app?

EDIT:

I mean ALL SMS sounds (horn, bell...etc).

END EDIT

Please don't tell me to record them :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`as the sound name.

Comment: Thats just one sound, what about the rest?

Comment: I think only the basic SMS sound is possible.